# What's the proper way to handle a patch request on the server

Tags: php, rest, http

Based on my research, the proper way to send a PATCH to JSON API is something like this:

```
PATCH /user/1 HTTP/1.1
{"op":"update", "resource":"name", "value":"bob"}
```

However I haven't found much info on how to handle this in server side code (I'm using PHP, but this isn't meant to be a language specific question). For a project I am currently working on I have a resource with several parameters that I think the PATCH request would be best suited for manipulating, and several different types of operations I would end up performing. My initial thought is to implement a switch like this

```
switch (request.body.op){
    case "update":
        //perform update on resource
    case "add":
        //add resource
    case "other":
        //some other operation
    default:
        //operation doesn't exist
}
```

but I thought I'd check if there is a more "proper" way to do this. Any input appreciated.